# error when connecting to remote MySQL (host gator) server using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am using Eclipse and I am trying to connect to my websites mysql database thru Host Gator.  This is the code I have so far in Eclipse in my Main.java file.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
//import java.sql.SQLException;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class Main 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://19x.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/kwinrow_storage","kwinrow_admin","xxxxxxx");
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM post_data WHERE type= 'mixtape' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next())
        {
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error from the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'kwinrow_admin'@'c-69-247-142-223.hsd1.tn.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1748)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I am I missing

Comment: It looks like you either don't have permission for user `kwinrow_admin` or the password you have is wrong. EITHER WAY You must change that password now that the whole world has it.

Comment: I changed the ip and password, hopefully to keep search engine crawlers from finding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security purposes HostGator will deny your connection request to the database by default.

You need to add your ip address to the list Remote Database Access Hosts.

here is a screenshot just in case you need it:

[image]

---

You can use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as an api to connect to your Database:

Here is an example in PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$query ='SELECT * FROM post_data WHERE type=:type ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute(array(':type'=>'mixtape'))) {
  $json = array();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $json[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($row);
}
```

I encoded the data in **[JSON](http://json.org/)** format.

Now your app is responsible for making a request to this script and the decode the JSON data.

Comment: Ok I will add my computer's ip address to host gator remote access database host. Now how would the app connect to the database if I am not on my home machine? Do I need to purchase a server?

Comment: @user3290428 because connecting directly to a database is never a good idea, I suggest you to write a service that will run on your server and expose your data to external authorized apps.

Comment: ok I will give that a try......any examples or references to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you know some php? which language are you familiar with

Comment: Your solution definintely helped and I am now accessing my database thru eclipse and i can view my query results in the emulator now!!!!!